# GreenRobot objectbox

Tags: android, database, sqlite, objectbox

Did anyone use ObjectBox for Android development?

- What is the minimum SDK it supports?
- Is the library stable?
- When should I use SQLite or ObjectBox in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. minSdkVersion is 15
2. It's used by thousands of apps, of which some have million of users
3. "Better" is highly subjective (I think I will edit your wording; it's probably causing downvotes). So some indicators: If you are looking for CRUD performance, ObjectBox is faster. If you like SQL, stick with SQLite/Room/whatever.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer helps me a lot